# How to delete orphan userdata from array in wp-options

Tags: customization, options

I have an option that subscribes members to forum email notifications. The list of emails is in an array as an option value. All is working fine and all subscribing and unsubscribing is done using `update_option();`

My problem is that were a user to be deleted it would be difficult to unsubscribe him without going into the database. So I thought this function would do it but I must be missing something :

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'forum_remove_deleted_user' );

function forum_remove_deleted_user($user_id)
{   
    $user_obj = get_userdata($user_id); 

    $subscbr_email = $user_obj->user_email;

    if(!empty($subscbr_email)) {                    
        $list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');

        if(!empty($list) &&  is_subscribed($subscbr_email)) {
            $key = array_search($subscbr_email, $list);
            unset($list[$key]);
        }               
    }       
}

function is_subscribed($subscbr_email)
{
    if($subscbr_email )
      {
        $list = (array)get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');
        if(in_array($subscbr_email , $list)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }     
}
```

I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong. Otherwise I suppose I could use `$wpdb` or perhaps I should?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Any idea where in that code it goes wrong?

Comment: I've used the code elsewhere in the project (before I came up with another way to do things) and everything went as expected.

Comment: You didn't even attempt to answer the questions asked, but @G-M may have spotted the problem.

Comment: I did var_dump or echo everything to answer your question. Thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what posted is all the code you are using, you unsetting the value from the retreved array using `unset`, but then you don't save again the array on database:

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'forum_remove_deleted_user' );

function forum_remove_deleted_user($user_id) {   
    $user_obj = get_userdata($user_id); 

    $subscbr_email = $user_obj->user_email;

    if( ! empty( $subscbr_email ) ) {                    
        $list = (array) get_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1');

        if( ! empty($list) && ( false !== array_search($subscbr_email, $list) ) ) {

            $key = array_search( $subscbr_email, $list );
            unset( $list[$key] );

            update_option('mf_forum_subscribers_1', $list); // you miss this part
        }               
    }       
}
```

For sake of semplicity I removed the dependency from `is_subscribed` function that is unneeded here.